# Connect to MySQL database on other domain

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a PHP website and MySQL database running at webhost X.
Now I have created another website in Ruby on Rails at webhost Y and I want it to get information from the MySQL database at webhost X. Is this possible and if so, how can it be done?

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a mysql user on webhost X , and allow it to access the database from webhost Y ip .

   Eg. grant all privileges on *.* to USER@IP identified by "PASSWORD";
2. On webhost Y , take the user you just created and connect as you would if the database where on localhost , but instead of localhost type webhost X ip address .

3 Securing ?? make shure firewall on webhost X allows access to the mysql port only from webhost Y ip address .

Answer (score 1):

Mysql support connection using port and hostname, as simple in CLI

```
mysql -u root -pxxx -h host_x -P 3306 ...
```

Take note that dns might fail to resolve sometime, connect using public IP is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need define the access to your database X in your database.yml. After you maybe need hack your model to be conform to your old database schema